# Is there a difference in sqlite and mysql while you are programming

Tags: sqlite

I want to learn SQLite for my computer science coursework. On youtube they most of the tutorials are on MYSQL. so I just want to confirm if there is a difference in SQLite and MYSQL while you write the program. I know that MYSQL can handle a bigger database and SQLite is just for smaller things. Does that mean there is a different way of writing it? for example programming languages Java and python could do similar stuff but the way we code is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using common SQL statements like SELECT, INSERT and CREATE TABLE there will be little difference.  Structured Query Language (SQL) is somewhat universal, but each DB engine has their own specialties and nuances about the syntax.  A good primer on SQL: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp

The main difference is your motivation for using it.    SQLite can actually handle a very large dataset but it doesn't support operations like Right or Outer Joins.  Here is a good starter for Python with SQLite: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/

Here is a good litmus test checklist for seeing if SQLite is the best choice for your project: https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

If you are trying to implement something simple I still think using MySQL is a better way to go.  MySQL has plenty of good install options to get you up and running quickly like MAMP(MacOS) or WAMP(Windows).  Of course, if you're running Linux there is always the tried and true LAMP stack all of these acronyms stand for Apache/MySQL/PHP where the first letter is the OS(Mac, Windows or Linux).  You can install these stacks and use only MySQL.  Plus I am sure the resources are much better for MySQL.

Last thing, MySQL offers a great GUI tool called PHPMyAdmin that can be used to manage MySQL DBs and tables.  This is great for new programmers to learn with.  You can run SQL statements in the GUI and export the raw SQL.